# background image not displaying in html css

Tags: html, css, image, background

This is my css code:

```
body
{
background-image:url("C:\xampp\htdocs\try\images\bg.jpg");
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title> HOPE Centre </title> </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" media="all" />
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<!--header-->
<header>
<div class="header">
<h1><img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\try\images\logo.png" alt="HOPE Centre" style="width:146px;height:83px></h1>
<nav>
<ul id="top_nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LogIn</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div> <!--end of div header-->
</header>

<!--main navigation-->
<div class="nav">
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">How to Help</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div> <!--end of div nav-->
</body>
</html>
```

Also the image in the heading  is not displaying.
The above code just displays a white background. I am using Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.103 m.
How should I fix this?

Comment: Check if the image actually exists at the specified location!

Comment: are you sure that is the correct path to the image?

Comment: the image exists and the path is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   body{background-image:url("../try/images/bg.jpg");}
```

or

```
   body{background-image:url("../../try/images/bg.jpg");}
```

where

```
Start with "/" returns to the root directory and starts here
Start with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts here
Start with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts here
```

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me. Best of luck!

```
body
{
    background-image:url("file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/try/images/bg.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
body
{
    background-image:url("images\bg.jpg");
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining the change and letting the OP know that there are only a few limited cases were using a URL that starts with C:\ are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Local pages frequently have a problem with loading local file:/// resouces. Use `http://localhost/try/images/bg.jpg`, since I see you're using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

try do this..
First of all, paste the image file where html file store like file name is "html.jpeg" And check your image format like .jpg,.jpeg,.png  etc

Doesn't matter of type format is capital form.

```
body {
        background-image: url("html.jpeg");
}
```